# Is it possible to host Free MAMP server on mac, and access mac localhost from iPhones on LAN?

Tags: mamp, web-hosting

I'm using Free MAMP to host my website. But I'm not able to see that web page from my iPhone which is in the same subnet/wifi as my Mac.

Please help me out.

Peace

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is go to a web browser and enter the ip of the machine running the mamp server followed by a colon (:) and 8888.

ex. 192.168.1.2:8888

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried localhost, 172.0.0.1 and mac ip address. I'm using Apple Airport for wifi

Comment: does localhost:8888 work on your mac, if not the server may not be running at all?

Comment: It does work on my Mac. But when I use, mimacip:8888 I got Forbidden error

Comment: Is there a firewall on your mac?

Comment: Thanks, for the help. There was something wrong with my iPhone, reboot and it works now with mac_ip:8888 :/